# Make a wxWidgets panel always repaint when it is resized

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a subclass of wxPanel inside a toplevel window with a couple of levels of wxSplitter above it. When the window is shown the some resizing and layout takes place. When it finishes the background of my panel has random junk (either black or other parts of the window) over some of its background. This seems to be a bug as it's using the bliting that is typically used to speed up scrolling, except that it's bliting from a location that doesn't belong to that panel.

Anyway, I figure I can fix it by making the window always repaint on resize and always draw the full contents of the wxPanel without any blitting. So: Is there any way to make it so the background of the wxPanel is always redrawn in full?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE` style for your panel, see `wxWindow` docs.

Another way is to catch `wxEVT_SIZE` and call `Refresh()` for the relevant panel (and maybe even `Update()` after it although be careful as this will become a rather expensive op).

Comment: Thanks. I tried handling the size event early on but it stopped layout working. After I looked at the source and realised you have to call layout yourself (and mark the event as handled) it worked. Setting the window style as you describe also works and is therefore the best solution as it's the simplest. I checked in the wxWidgets docs and it does say repainting in Windows might be buggy and to set wxFULL_PAINT_ON_RESIZE if it's a problem(!)